# How to print barcodes numbers in same row from seperate records?

Tags: sql, printing

Barcode numbers are stored as seperate records with a bar_id of either 1 or 0. I need to print them to a csv file in side by side columns.

```
barcodes.bar_barcode is the barcodes field
barcodes.bari_id defines where it is barcode 1 or 0
barcodes.bar_description is the description field
```

Here is the data and output needed:

[image: table]

I just don't know how to print the two barcodes in side by side columens.

Answer (score 0):

Do you always have a BAR_ID 0 and 1 for each BAR_BARCODE? If so, you can probably do what you want with a self-join. Otherwise you may need to look at using outer joins as well.

```
SELECT a.BAR_BARCODE, b.BAR_BARCODE
  FROM BARCODES a
      ,BARCODES b
  WHERE a.BAR_ID = 1
    AND b.BAR_ID = 0
    AND a.BAR_INVNO = b.BAR_INVNO
```

UPDATE

Try using an outer join to accommodate the missing bar_id = 0 records.

```
SELECT a.BAR_BARCODE, COALESCE(b.BAR_BARCODE, 'value when null')
  FROM BARCODES a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BARCODES b ON (a.BAR_INVNO = b.BAR_INVNO AND b.BAR_ID = 0)
  WHERE a.BAR_ID = 1
```

Comment: This is good but some bar_id=0 may be null in the bar_barcode field.  All bar_id=1 will have a barcode.  How do I handle the null's?